# Merge dataframe columns that contain a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a list :

```
id  rl
a   [c,v,b,n]
b   []
c   [x,a]
....
```

and i want to merge the cells like this

```
merged
a,c,v,b,n
b
c,x,a
```

I tried this `pd.DataFrame({'merged' : fdf.groupby(['id'])['rel'].apply(",".join)}).reset_index()` but i get this error `expected str instance, list found`
Any ideas?

Comment: how are those lists declared? as strings?

Comment: I read the lists from a csv file. When i user `.str` i  get the `unhashable type : list error`

Comment: What is the raw data from the csv file.

Comment: The data from the csv file are in the dataframe with the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [11]:
ind = pd.Series(df.index)
ind
Out[11]:
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

In [20]:
list_string = df.rl.map(lambda x : ','.join(x))
list_string
Out[20]:
a    c,v,b,n
b           
c        x,a
Name: rl, dtype: object

In [22]:
final = ind.str.cat(list_string, sep = ',')
final
Out[22]:
0    a,c,v,b,n
1           b,
2        c,x,a
dtype: object

# to remove the comma at the end of string you can simply do the following
# final.str.replace(',$' , '')
# 0    a,c,v,b,n
# 1            b
# 2        c,x,a
# dtype: object

In [24]:
pd.DataFrame(final , columns=['merged'])
Out[24]:
    merged
0   a,c,v,b,n
1   b,
2   c,x,a
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can i now compare this dataframe to another that looks like it and find keep only the elements of the first dataframe that exist on the second dataframe

Comment: as for `pd.DataFrame(final , columns=['merged'])` it is not working properly and i changed it with `final.to_frame()` that works!

Comment: What is the error you've gotten , it should work fine

Comment: it shows an empty dataframe with merged as column name. I checked and everything before this works properly